# Loop exiting prematurely

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, loops

I want to write a function that accepts a list and a number as an argument. It will return a list of the items that add up to that number.

For example `func([1,2,3,4,5],7)` should return `[5,2]`. But the program only returns `[5]` now.

This is a simplified version of the algorithm that I will be using as a part of a larger project, the original version will have a lot more conditionals, but if this works, I can build on top of that, hence I am going to ignore things that will break the program such as no elements adding up, etc, for now.

```
def func(R,t):
    
    tog = t
    appr = 0
    rlist = []
    
    while True:
        
        if appr >= tog:
            break
        
        diff = [t-i for i in R]
        for i,v in enumerate(diff):
            if v == min(diff):
                rlist.append(R[i])
                appr += R[i]
                t -= R[i]
                R.remove(R[i])
                break
        return rlist
```

The idea is that whichever element (from list R) is the least different to the target (t) will be added to `rlist`, and that value will be dropped from the list sent as the argument. When the target value is reached, the main loop is broken.

An explanation of why this is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.

EDIT - `diff [abs(tog - i) for i in R]` works.

Comment: Should 3 and 4 also be included for your example? How about 1 + 2 + 4? Should those 3 numbers be included, or are you just interested in pairs?

Comment: @mhawke , I want the lowest number of items needed, so 5,2 given my algo is written such that it will chose 5 first as it is closest to 7

Answer (score 1):

`return rlist` has incorrect indentation. It will be called once the `for` loop terminates.

You probably meant for the return to be after the `while` loop, so remove one level of indentation for the `return` statement.

Now you will get more results in the list, but it will probably be wrong.

As an aside, `R.remove(R[i])` will remove items from the list passed into `func()`. The calling code probably doesn't expect that the list it passes to `func()` will be modified.

Comment: @bboyenergetic you mentioned your answer should be `[5,2]`

Comment: @toRex, yes, but I am getting [5,4], which means its ignoring the changed value of t